# Consulta Mysqli

Tags: php, jquery

tengo un formulario que me manda los datos a la base y otro que me trae esos datos a un PDF. mi consulta como puedo hacer que me traiga los datos de la maquina que se  llena el formulario. les pongo el programa que me trae esos datos. 
tengo que limitar de alguna forma sino me trae todo la información de la base y necesito solo que traiga lo de la maquina que se completo el formulario.

```
><?php
    >include_once('FPDF/fpdf.php');
        >$pdf = new fpdf();
        >$pdf->AddPage();

    >class PDF extends fpdf{
    >function Header(){
        >$this->Image('imagenes/logocampusheader.png', 5, 5,200,25);
        >$this->Ln(30);
    >}
    >function footer(){
        >$this->Ln(-25);
        >$this->MultiCell(120, 5, utf8_decode('Plataforma de Capacitación 
         >del Ministerio de Producción y Trabajo Capacitación: 
         >capacitacionrrhh@produccion.gob.ar 
         >Asistencia Técnica: campus@produccion.gob.ar').$this- 
         >SetTextColor(0, 0, 
         >255) .$this->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255) .$this- 
         >SetXY(10,-18),0,1,0);
         >$this->Image(('imagenes/Logo-ministerio.png') .$this- 
         >SetXY(10,-25),142,280,65);
         >}
       >}



        >$pdf = new PDF();
        >$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        >$pdf->AddPage();
        >$pdf->SetFillColor(0, 191, 255);
        >$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0); 
        >require 'basedatos.php';

        >$consulta = "SELECT * FROM campus";
        >$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta); 
        >$consulta1 = "SELECT * FROM gestores";
        >$resultado1 = $mysqli->query($consulta1);
        >$consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM profesores";
        >$resultado2 = $mysqli->query($consulta2);


>error_reporting(0);
     >ini_set('display_errors', 0);
         >$pdf->Cell(40,10, 'Nombre del Curso',1,0,'C',0);
         >$pdf->Cell(36,10, 'Cantidad de Modulos',1,0,'C',0);
         >$pdf->Cell(35,10, 'Fecha de Inicio',1,0,'C',0);
         >$pdf->Cell(38,10, 'Fecha de Finalizacion',1,0,'C',0);
         >$pdf->Cell(40,10, 'Cantidad de Comisiones',1,1,'C',0);




     >while($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
     >$arrayGeneral = array();
     >array_push($arrayGeneral,$rows);
     >foreach ($arrayGeneral as $row){
     >$pdf->Cell(40,10, utf8_decode($row['Nombre del Curso']),1,0,'C',1);
     >$pdf->Cell(36,10, $row['Cantidad de Modulos'],1,0,'C',1);
     >$pdf->Cell(35,10, utf8_decode($row['Fecha de Inicio']),1,0,'C',1);
     >$pdf->Cell(38,10, utf8_decode($row['Fecha de 
     >Finalizacion']),1,0,'C',1);
     >$pdf->Cell(40,10, $row['Cantidad de Comisiones'],1,1,'C',1);
          >}
      >}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es “la máquina que llena el formulario”?

Comment: desde alguna pc se llena un formulario y lo manda a la base de datos

Comment: ¿Qué dato “de la máquina que llena el formulario” necesitas para hacer el filtrado?

Comment: supongo que con el IP de las maquinas se conectan se podria sacar esa informacion

Answer (score 0):

Guilhermo,
Hay que poner filtros en tus consultas. Por ese motibo es que estas trayendo todos los datos de la base. Vea tu consulta abajo:

````
        >$consulta = "SELECT * FROM campus"; --> // el (*)  traerá todos los datos.
        >$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta); 
        >$consulta1 = "SELECT * FROM gestores"; -->// el (*)  traerá todos los datos.
        >$resultado1 = $mysqli->query($consulta1);
        >$consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM profesores"; -->// el (*)  traerá todos los datos.
        >$resultado2 = $mysqli->query($consulta2);
```
Recuerda que el formulario tiene que contener por ejemplo la fecha de Inicio e Fecha de Finalazacion.
````

```
     >$pdf->Cell(35,10, 'Fecha de Inicio',1,0,'C',0);
     >$pdf->Cell(38,10, 'Fecha de Finalizacion',1,0,'C',0);
```

```
**Mira un ejemplo que pueda te ayudar:**
```

SELECT nombre_profesor,nombre_curso,fecha_inicio,fecha_finalizacion
WHERE fecha_inicio between '$variable del formulario' and '$variable del formulario'
AND fecha_finalizacion between '$variable del formulario' and '$variable del formulario'
FROM profesores